# How to create a new column in SQL based on information in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, text, alter

I am trying to search message codes within 1 table and think it would be easier if I create a new column that specifies each code within the column with the corresponding formula.

So I am trying to create a new column within the table called MessageCode which specifies each number after "MessageCode": but I am not sure how to do this. In the end I want a table that basically gives back Id, Title, Enabled, Message Code and Actions.

If you need further information please let me know.Also I am using SSMS.

```
ID      Title     Enabled Mark Colour       Condition                                                     Action
1914    ABW: 012    1       -256           {"Operator":1,"Children":[{"Operator":1,"LeftOperand":}  [{"ActionType":1,"Results":[{"ExcludeApplicationGroups":[5],"IncludeEZY":false,"StartDate":"2022-07-08T00:00:00","MessageCode":9109,"Ordinal":32,"Level":2,"Status":2,"LocalisedMessages":[{"Message":"<p>Passengers are advised to hold travel insurance that covers Covid-19.</p>"},{"LanguageId":50,"Message":"<p>Passagiers wordt aangeraden een reisverzekering af te sluiten die het Covid-19 dekt.</p>"},{"LanguageId":75,"Message":"<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong>Il est conseillé aux passagers d'avoir une assurance voyage qui couvre le Covid-19.</p>"},{"LanguageId":156,"Message":"<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong>Se aconseja a los pasajeros que tengan un seguro de viaje que cubra Covid-19.</p>"},{"LanguageId":140,"Message":"<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong>Os passageiros são aconselhados a possuir um seguro de viagem que cubra o Covid-19.</p>"},{"LanguageId":141,"Message":"<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong>Aconselha-se os passageiros a possuírem um seguro de viagem que cubra o Covid-19.</p>"}]}]}]
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle. SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)

Comment: Sorry just added that, using SSMS

Comment: Also, please don't use images. Add all information directly to your question as editable text. This allows someone, who wants to try out a solution, to copy your data - rather than having to re-type it from scratch

Comment: There you go just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the below query to read the value from Action column

```
SELECT ID, Title, Enabled, MarkColour, Condition,
       JSON_VALUE(Action, '$[0].Results[0].MessageCode') AS MessageCode
FROM <YourTableName>
```